# Idiomatic C API with regards to pointers

Tags: c, api-design, pointers

I am trying to get a better understanding of how one would structure an API in C.

- I create a struct `Person`
- I have a `init` function that sets data on that struct
- I have multiple "helper" functions that work on that struct

I'm wondering if the following code in C can be considered idiomatic from the point of view of more seasoned C developers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Person Person;

struct Person
{
    unsigned int age;
    unsigned int weight;
    Person *next_person;
};

void person_init(Person *p, unsigned int age, unsigned int weight, Person *next_person) 
{
    p->age = age;
    p->weight = weight;
    p->next_person = next_person;
}

void person_print(Person *p)
{
    printf("person is %dy old\n", p->age);
    printf("person weight is %dkg\n", p->weight);
}

int main(void) 
{
    Person p1, p2, p3, p4;
    Person *p_cur;

    person_init(&p1, 28, 80, &p2);    
    person_print(&p1);

    person_init(&p2, 58, 93, &p3);  
    person_print(&p2);

    person_init(&p3, 60, 60, &p4);  
    person_print(&p3);

    person_init(&p4, 78, 50, NULL);  
    person_print(&p4);

    printf("==================\n");

    p_cur = &p1;

    while (p_cur != NULL) {
        person_print(p_cur);
        p_cur = p_cur->next_person;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In particular I'm unsure about the **signature of the functions** in general and about the use of a `Person *` pointer.

When is it OK to not-pass a pointer but the struct/char array directly?

In most APIs I have seen so far, a pointer to the struct/char array is passed, like [`snprintf(char * s, ... )`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/). But sometimes, like in [`getline(char **lineptr, ...)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) even a `char **` is passed. Why? When make the distinction?

Comment: `char *` pretty much means "String" in old-style C, because there is no built-in `String` type. Read `char **` as `String *` and things look much more consistent.

Comment: OK @KilianFoth, that makes sense. But when do you use one over the other?

Comment: To expand a bit more, because to me it looks like getline could use a `char *` just as well?

Comment: yah, it's nothing different from terminating a `char` string with `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a matter of *opinion*, however, it looks like `Person` is generally supposed to be allocated in the heap (read about [C dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)).

Then you should define and *document* how `Person`-s are allocated and who is in charge of `free`-ing them and when.

I would suggest to have a function to create `Person`-s like

```
Person* make_person(unsigned p_age, p_weight) {
   Person* p = malloc(sizeof(Person));
   if (!p) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   p->age = p_age;
   p->weight = p_weight;
   p->next_person = NULL;
}
```

We don't know what is `next_person` for. We might guess you want to have a *global* linked list of `Person`-s. Then you want some *global* pointer to the head of that list, the `make_person` should modify that global pointer, etc.

I would recommend against having `Person` automatic variables on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) (in particular, because that would limit the number of `Person`-s your program can handle, often to some staticly known small number; you may want to be able to handle millions of `Person`-s) Intuitively the call stack should not grow a lot (on current desktops with ordinary OSes like Linux or Windows, a stack limit of a few megabytes is typical) But we don't know what are you really coding.

Be afraid of [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). Read something about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29). In a few months, you might be interested by [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/). If your system has it, consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) -for debugging purposes.

You might want a `void destroy_person(Person*p)` function which would either recursively (or iteratively) call `destroy_person` on the `p->next_person` or remove it from your global list, then call `free(p)` ...

Comment: Nothing in particular, I'm trying to understand how to structure an API. Why does it look to you like Person should be dynamically allocated? Those are the questions I am interested in.

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand i guess … its better if my functions take a pointer, then the client code is free to either allocate on the heap or stack. Does that make sense?

Comment: Practically not. You need to decide very early that every `Person` is heap allocated.

Answer (score 2):

Different linked libraries may use different heaps. This makes dynamic allocation and memory management tricky.

The most common way is to make Person an opaque struct (declared but not defined in the public header) and the programmer using it must use the functions in the library to get access to the attributes.

This means that allocating and freeing will be done inside the library using functions like `Person* create_person(...)` and `void destroy_person(Person*)`.

Comment: Having different heaps for different libraries is uncommon, and definitely out of the scope of some beginner... Most libraries share *the* usual C heap (e.g. `malloc` & `free`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch but something to be aware of either way, easiest way to work around is to ensure only 1 library can allocate and destroy all instances of an object.

Comment: But different heaps mean that `libA` is using the system `malloc` but `libB` is using some other `malloc` - e.g. its own one based on `mmap` - and this is not common. For most programmers, there is only *one* C heap, provided by system `malloc` & `free` functions.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch or one of both uses a static C-runtime (with a maloc/free based on the same things as the system C-runtime but using its own globals) rather than one linked in by the system. Either way if you want an extended debate you can find me on [programmer's chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).